# Usage of UnderscoresJS _.pluck with Meteor users collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, underscore.js, meteor-accounts

I've got an issue with _.pluck in Meteor. I've got a working subscription to the users collection that I've tested with a console.log. All users are being fetched. When I do a _.pluck(users, 'username') I get an error in the console - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null.` Code below:

```
MattersController.helpers({
  'matterAccess': function(access) {
    if (access) {
      var users = Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: {'username': 1}});
      // console.log(users);
      var usernames = _.pluck(users, 'username');
      console.log(usernames);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

Please ignore the access param - it does return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well "find" comes back with a cursor and not actual array. In order to have an array use fetch().

```
var users = Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: {'username': 1}}).fetch();
```